# Can a person hack bitcoin private keys and legally claim the bitcoins for himself?

Tags: property, ownership, cryptocurrency, cryptography

First, some background knowledge — bitcoins are a form of cryptocurrency that can be stored in "addresses". Each bitcoin address is linked to a specific private key. To access bitcoins in a specific address, a person needs a private key in order to do so. To put simply — for each bitcoin address (analogous to a bank account), there is a corresponding private key (analogous to a password) to unlock and access the bitcoins.

Now, let's say some genius finds a previously unknown mathematical method to crack private keys faster than brute force. Can he **legally** claim bitcoins for himself by doing the following?

1. He deliberately finds bitcoin addresses that have been *dormant for years* (indicating that it is very possible that their owners have lost their keys and are unable to access the coins. Lost bitcoins are very common - approximately 20% of all bitcoins in existence are lost.), and hacks their private keys.
2. He transacts the coins to a custodial address first.
3. He then sends a message to the hacked address and informs the owners that he has found their bitcoins, and requests that the owner claim them within a specific time period.
4. Once the deadline is up, and no one shows up to claim the coins, he takes them for himself.

In this case, would the "finders keepers" law apply? Meaning that if I find someone else's money, I try to inform the owner and no one shows up to claim the money, I can basically take the money for myself.

I'm asking this question because there is a group known as the "Large Bitcoin Collider" who is trying to brute force other people's private keys and claim the funds for themselves. According to the group, it will give the original owner six months to claim the funds before the group takes the money for themselves, which is "in accordance with European laws." Is this actually legal? (See [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1573035.160))

Comment: In the UK there is no "finders keepers" law for physical property. If you find someone's property (e.g. a cellphone) then it remains their property, and if you keep it then you are a thief. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-39130530

Comment: @PaulJohnson Except "If you make a reasonable attempt to find the person who lost it and they don't come forward, you could keep [your discovery] with a clear conscience," - such as, posting the address and waiting a couple of months; some countries have specific time periods such as 6 months or 12 months in the law.

Comment: This isn't conceptually different from picking up someone's safe and finding its lock combination, then claiming the safe's contents.

Comment: "He then sends a message to the hacked address" - how exactly can you send a message to the hacked address? As far as I know, bitcoin addressess are anonymous.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/65uoaq/do_not_run_the_large_bitcoin_collider_client_its/

Comment: There's a basic problem here, erroneously exemplified by the phrase common among cryptocurrency enthusiasts => "not your keys, not your crypto". If I have a magic 8ball that can look at a public bitcoin address with 100,000 BTC in it, and I can *snap* click my fingers and derive the private key for that public address, then I can move those coins just as the "other holder of the private key" can and the network cannot tell who was the original sole holder of the private key that could transfer those coins. Indeed, I could stand up and say "but *I'm* spartacus!" and noone can tell us apart...

Comment: ..I'm not sure the law is down with the concepts inherent in [not] possessing crypto and the amount of legwork you would have to do to attach realistic and tangible ownership to crypto is quite bizarre. What is being discussed here is essentially one person being able to guess a number known only by another person, and (if they do) the rest of the world being able to know (or care) the difference enough to maintain the notion of assigned ownership. I think the problem you'll hit is that on a technical level crypto isn't owned, it's just passing through people who have the ability to send it on

Comment: @CaiusJard:  I don't think the law cares about the details of passwords.  If the bitcoins belong to A and person B somehow gets the password (whether by mathematical techniques or finding it on a piece of paper in A's house or trash) and takes the bitcoins without A's permission, it is theft.  It may be hard to prove that B did it contrary to A's wishes, but that is not the question here.  Here it is assumed they were taken without permission

Comment: Two important points: (1) for a single crypto wallet, there is a large number of keys that will work (on average, say, 1 billion different keys). The intent of the authors is to find (in the general case) a different key. A lockpicking in its pure form, in a lot of jurisdictions there is a separate punishment for it. And (2), the whole discussion is more or less theoretical, because as of now, finding a key for a certain wallet is still WAY harder than the honest mining for new coins.

Comment: @RossMillikan it's the "belongs to" bit that I don't get on with. Bitcoins aren't "things" that can belong, and anyone who could notionally claim to have a bitcoin balance in actuality simply has, stored in their computer/trezor/safe, a number that they can use to create a bitcoin transaction and publish it on a network to make a transfer to someone else. No one has "a bitcoin" - they just have a sum of increments minus a sum of decrements and a way to create a decrement that will be someone else's increment via a number. The number is hard to guess but if can, in theory be guessed. This...

Comment: ...isn't like stealing someone's safe and guessing the combination, nor breaking into someone's house and taking their hard drive/piece of paper with a bitcoin private key on. This is about being able to sit down and think of a random number and it working out to be the same number someone else knows and could used to create a transaction- but because there isn't any ownership associated with the number the network cannot tell who the first person to have that number was, if that would even legitimately be an "owner".. With no authority with which to lay claim to a number, what is possession?

Comment: **In this case, would the "finders keepers" law apply?** why would any such law apply?  You haven't "found" anything, you've done the equivalent of hang around at a bike rack, cracked the combination on a lock, and posted a note for a day or two saying "if no one claims this bike, I'm having it".  There is no "finding" here, it's basically theft with some wrapping.

Comment: @CaiusJard the technical and mathematical details are irrelevant to the concept of ownership, which is a legal/social issue. If courts interpret ownership of bitcoins as meaningful (and they do), then they have full authority to enforce that "claim to a number" and assert an exclusive *legal* right (distinct from actual ability to sign transactions validated by the network) to make transactions using that number; prohibit others from making transactions with that number and if anyone violates that prohibition, then apply whatever corrective and/or punitive actions are appropriate.

Comment: @CaiusJard in essence, the main flaw in your argument is in the assertion that there isn't any legitimate owner; courts in various countries have asserted that there *is* legitimate ownership of bitcoin. What (e.g.) bitcoin network enforces is conceptually about *possession*, which is fundamentally distinct from ownership. If someone has possession of something I own (e.g. the private keys to some bitcoin where I can successfully assert in court that any value derived from them belongs to me) then I have the legal right to force them to return possession or compensate me with other assets.

Comment: @Peteris I'm still struggling with your use of the phrase "I own". I understand the concept in the legal/societal sense but if the courts have applied it to bitcoin it can only be via erroneous import of the societal convention. When you said "I own", presuming you're talking about crypto, by what authority do you assert ownership? How do you prove you own this crypto? May I say, in the same fashion, that I own the moon?

Comment: @CaiusJard by what authority do you assert ownership of anything else, whether a shirt on your shoulders or a car parked next to your home? In general, law recognizes the concept of transferrable ownership for many different kinds of incorporeal assets, rights and claims. The specific details depend on the jurisdiction, but in general courts worldwide have acknowledged that this also applies to cryptocurrencies. One reasonable and popular way of asserting that you own a particular cryptocurrency asset would be through provenance, the (possibly implicit) contract through which you received it.

Comment: @CaiusJard Furthermore, I don't understand your statement "via erroneous import of the societal convention". The legal system is the one that defines the extent to which that societal convention applies, legal rules alone determine whether it's appropriate or erroneous to extend this convention to cryptocurrencies. If the legal acts and courts define that the societal concept of ownership applies to cryptocurrencies as well, then that determination is axiomatically correct.

Comment: @Peteris I am far from being knowledgeable about BTC, but isn't the whole point of BTC the fact that it can be independent of courts and sovereigns? Or have I been exposed to too much cypherpunkism?

Comment: OK, this is progress. So you go along to the courts and say "I own that crypto because I got it from him when..." and you can keep going like that, all the way back to the person who mined it.. And they prove they got it because they can show they did the work and the network acknowledges it. Leaving out the part you said before where the network acknowledges possession, not ownership (and also leaving out privacy coins where this chain cannot be established), what do you do when that chain breaks down? What does the court do when two people appear with exactly the same story?

Comment: @CaiusJard you don't need to go all the way back to the person who mined it. If the other party contests ownership, the court can and will unilaterally decide who's right; they don't need a perfect proof, far from it, preponderance of the evidence is sufficient. Resolving disputes where two people appear with similarly valid contradictory claims is the whole reason why we have courts.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo you're right in that the currencies themselves *can* be free of sovereignty and control, but it tends to be that they're moved around and considered societally owned by human beings that *are* subject to sovereignty etc. Part of this thing I'm picking apart with Peteris is over that notion of ownership; I'm coming from a standpoint that bitcoin cannot be *technically* owned; he's coming from the perspective that they can be *legally* owned, and because anyone who moves a bitcoin is ultimately doing so on a computer in a country with a legal system, that's all that matters

Comment: I'm pointing out (a lack of) technical ownership because of the specific context of the question; I'd like to know what the legal system does in the case of an *uncontested* claim of legal ownership as a result of deducing a way to technically possess the coins in a particular address

Comment: @CaiusJard thank you for the summary of my position, it seems reasonable and accurate. Regarding 'uncontested claim' - if nobody else cares, then the legal system does not get involved and possession is the only thing that matters until there is some dispute. But I don't think that this question is about uncontested claims, it's about claims that are uncontested *for now*, it's asking whether one can do this and consider themselves safe from some future claims by someone claiming to own these coins long after the fact, and IMHO no, they can't be totally safe.

Comment: @Peteris so my next question is, if there's a country/jurisdiction that supports the notion of finders-keepers, and someone from there has the same private key that i have (however it came about that they have it), and my jurisdiction is different (and supports or doesn't support the notion of f-k), absent any unified binding authority that we are both subject to, do the bitcoins in the relevant address have a single legal owner? It seems like my legal system will recognize me, their legal system will recognize them and no way to reconcile this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the UK it is an offence to cause a computer to gain unauthorised access to any program or data held in any computer ([s1 Computer Misuse Act 1990](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/1)).

It seems likely that other European jurisdictions have similar laws. Certainly Germany does: Penal Code 202a data espionage ([German text](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__202a.html) - [English translation](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1875)). (I mention Germany because the linked thread does.)

It might constitute theft in the jurisdiction if the finder did not take reasonable steps to find the owner - which may include informing the police of the find.

Depending on the jurisdiction it might count as 'treasure' or abandoned property such that the finder is obliged to inform the authorities (the jurisdiction has the presumption of ownership of abandoned or lost property - e.g. Scotland), which then decide what to do with it.

Legally speaking it seems to me that, to declare it legal, we have to get over such hurdles.

[edit]

There seems to be some dispute in the comments that cryptocurrency is subject to any regulation, counts as property, is something of value or is something that is owned and can be stolen, such that the person in the questioner's scenario could be held to account under the law for his behaviour.

Aren't they merely numbers? No - plainly they do have value because people trade them with currency and goods and services. The UK's tax authority, HMRC, "does not consider cryptoassets to be currency or money" but sees them as having economic value because "they can be 'turned to account' - for example, exchanging them for goods, services, fiat currency (that is money declared by a government to be legal tender) or other tokens". They are "a new type of intangible asset". Individuals are liable "to pay UK tax if they are a UK resident and carry out a transaction with their tokens which is subject to UK tax". They are liable for "Income Tax and National Insurance contributions on cryptoassets which they receive from their employer as a form of non-cash payment [or from] mining, transaction confirmation or airdrops." ([HMRC cryptoassets for individuals](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/tax-on-cryptoassets/cryptoassets-for-individuals))

Are they property? Something that can be owned, something that can be dishonestly appropriate (i.e. stolen)? That's the interesting dispute.

Recently, the High Court of England and Wales ruled in a bitcoin ransomware-related case that "for the purpose of granting an interim injunction in the form of an interim proprietary injunction ... crypto currencies are a form of property capable of being the subject of a proprietary injunction". In that judgment there is some discussion of the authorities for considering or deciding they are property. ([[2019] EWHC 3556 (Comm)](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/Comm/2019/3556.html)) read from para 50 if not the whole judgment.

In at least two other cryptocurrency-related cases the High Court treated the cryptocurrency as property. Vorotyntseva v Money-4 Limited, trading as Nebeus.com [2018] EWHC 2598 (Ch) and Liam David Robertson v Persons Unknown 2019.

There was also a suggestion in the comments that the police would not understand and would not be interested. But there are several jurisdictions where people have been investigated, arrested, prosecuted and convicted of crimes relating to cryptocurrencies. A simple internet search for bitcoin theft, fraud or money laundering will result in some reports. In any case their interest or lack of it is irrelevant to what the law may say.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107013/discussion-on-answer-by-lag-can-a-person-hack-bitcoin-private-keys-and-legally-c).

Comment: re: "it is an offence to cause a computer to gain unauthorised access to any program or data held in any computer".  Even your own?  The blockchain information is distributed to every user of bitcoins.  So this would amount to gaining access to some of the encrypted information on one's own computer.  And the encrypted information was made public by its original creators.  Is it really the case that I can't decrypt any information that a 3rd party got me to copy to my computer in an encrypted format?

Comment: @grovkin I don't think the CMA has been tested in that respect. But there isn't an absolute freedom to do anything you want with data on your computer. Take reverse engineering for example: there isn't an absolute freedom to reverse engineer software regardless of your method or how you intend to use the information. It depends on how you do it and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that you can't run an anti-virus program?  It removes (and in doing so accesses) viruses despite a lack of authorization from a virus maker?  While I ask this in jest, it demonstrates the general principle that you can't know what is hidden in the data/programs that are present on your own computer unless you have the right (even if not the ability) to examine it.

Comment: @grovkin Surely this depends on who can authorise what? In the infinitesimally unlikely event there is a prosecuted complaint from the virus writer, I think it's reasonable to assume the court will rule that you can authorise yourself to run anti-virus software on your computer for the purpose of checking for and removing viruses from your computer. I don't think it's reasonable to assume a court would rule that you can authorise yourself to do something with data on your computer for the purpose of dishonestly enriching yourself at someone else's expense.

Comment: @Lag if it's an "offense", would it require a complaint from the virus maker?  I am not sure what the British word for it is, but can't the Crown do what is called "bring charges" in the US?  Isn't that what it means for it to be a criminal offense?  And again, it's not about the likelihood of prosecution.  It's probably equally unlikely that someone would be charged for finding a private key matching a public key that is distributed to everyone in the BTC ledger.

Comment: @Lag it's not about authorizing yourself to run a program.  It's about conducting unauthorized introspection of a program which you weren't meant to access by the program's creator.  I am not sure why you bring intent ("...for the purpose of...") into it.  Does intent matter for this law?  Or does the law make the process of conducting these actions illegal regardless of intent?

Comment: @grovkin I should have recalled the interpretation section of the CMA as amended, s17(8): "An act done in relation to a computer is unauthorised if the person doing the act (or causing it to be done)—(a) is not himself a person who has responsibility for the computer and is entitled to determine whether the act may be done; and (b) does not have consent to the act from any such person." So the CMA doesn't prohibit you from affecting the data on your computer. However, wouldn't the method described in the OP necessarily affect the blockchain that is distributed to all participating computers?

Comment: or other data on computers not owned or authorised for use by the person following that method?

Comment: @Lag I am not sure if it would.  There are 2 steps here.  Step 1: finding a private key from the public key.  If this is done mathematically (and that's less likely than using some backdoor that's built into all modern CPUs), then no other computer is accessed.  Step 2: using that private key to transfer funds to a different BTC "wallet." This maybe considered "unauthorized access." Except that all the computers participating in the blockchain consent to private keys themselves acting as authorizations regardless of who uses them. it's like a carrier check.  Possession authorizes access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107730/discussion-between-lag-and-grovkin).